# How am I notified a buyer if my option was exercised by the buyer on TWS? How much delay is there from when exercised to when I'm notified?

Tags: options, call-options

If I sell a call option out of the money that goes in the money before expiration, and if the buyer chooses to exercise the option before expiration, is there an immediate or delayed notification in TWS?

TWS=Trader Work Station (Interactive Brokers)

Comment: What does "TWS" stand for?

Comment: @Chris W. Rea - TWS stands for TraderWorkstation at Interactive Brokers.  It's their standalone trading platform.  But now that you mention it, it's possible that my assumption might be incorrect that that's the TWS he is referring to.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question to clarify what TWS I am referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Traders submit exercise notices during (and after) market hours and their brokers notify the OOC.  In the evening, the OCC uses an electronic "Wheel"  to randomly determine assignments which are then sent to the brokers who then use their own in house method to determine who gets assigned.

With IBKR, your end of day E-mail statement will contain the details of the assignment transaction.  So that means **very late the same day to early the next morning**, depending on whether it's a normal trading day or expiration.  This information would be available in your online statement as well.